# Добавление элемента в список на Python

Tags: python, list, for, append

В Python, при добавлении элемента в список с помощью append, я ожидаю увидеть нечто вроде:

```
['31955189', '38274957']
```

Но при выполнении следующего кода (добавляю элементы в пустой список):

```
def get(item, field):
  result = []
  for items in field:
    popitka = int(todos2['response'][item][items])
    result.append(popitka)
  return result
second = []
for i, item in enumerate(todos2['response']):
  second.append(get(i, ['id']))
```

у меня выходит следующее:

```
['[31955189]', '[38274957]', '[40975081]']
```

Что не так? Как избавиться от этих не эстетичных квадратных скобочек? По сути, у меня выходят вложенные в список списки, то есть при каждой итерации добавляется уже список, состоящий из одного элемента. По окончании решения данной мне задачи эти лишние скобки, то есть вложенные в список списки мне будут мешать. Мне нужны только данные. Запихивать их глубоко в подсписок не нужно.
Но, если выполнить нечто подобное следующему, то можно добиться необходимого результата:

```
second = tuple(second[0]) #Нужно для каждого добавленного элемента.
#Можно через for, но у меня есть сомнения в правильности этого действия.
print(second)
#Result: (20834091,)
```

Но выполнять эту неприятную процедуру нужно для каждого добавленного элемента.
А вот так это выглядит без извращений, но мне это не подходит (выхлоп мне не нравится):

```
second = tuple(second)
print(second)
print(second[0])
#Result: ['[31955189]', '[38274957]', '[40975081]']
#Result: [31955189]
```

Быть может я просто запарился и проблемы нет?

Comment: Покажите что у вас в `todos2`.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то у вас result возвращает по одну элементу и насколько понимаю какое-то число, тогда сделать так чтобы функция возвращала не список, а число (int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте разбираться.

В итоговый список `second` вы добавляете результаты функции `get`. Функция `get` за каждый вызов возвращает `result`. А `result` - это список. Логично, что в итоге у вас и получится список списков.

Решить проблему можно если просто заменить в последней строчке `second.append` на `second.extend` тогда у вас вместо вставки списка `result` в `second` он будет просто дописываться в конец.

Но вообще, кажется, что ваше решение очень переусложнено и задачу можно решить вообще в одну строчку:

```
second = [int(item['id']) for item in todos2['response']]
```

Проверить не могу, так как вы не привели пример содержимого `todos2`, но, кажется, это должно работать.